# How to load images in asset folder in file object? I am getting an error "No such file or directory, errno = 2"

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, file, plugins, flutter

I am trying to implement aws_ai plugin for flutter https://pub.dev/packages/aws_ai for Face Comparision with AWS Rekognition. The code is stated clearly in the example. It says load image in the object type file. How to do it?

assume that my image, abc.jpg is in asset folder: 
- they are initialized in pubspec.yaml and I have run flutter packages get

I have tried `Image.file(File('assets/abc.jpg'))`: it throws the error that image type cannot be assigned to file type.

I have also tried `var sourceImagefile = new File('assets/abc.jpg');` : it is throwing the error of no such file

```
import 'package:aws_ai/src/RekognitionHandler.dart';

---> File sourceImagefile, targetImagefile; //load source and target images in those File objects
String accessKey, secretKey, region ; //load your aws account info in those variables

RekognitionHandler rekognition = new RekognitionHandler(accessKey, secretKey, region); 
Future<String> labelsArray = rekognition.compareFaces(sourceImagefile, targetImagefile);
```

I need code for input to be given at ---> line. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did u imported the image on pubspec.yaml?

```
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - assets/image_01.png
  - assets/image_02.png
  - assets/image_03.png
```

Comment: Yes, thanks I have edited the question now but I have already initialized them. I needed the code to load image in file object.